# Regex101 vs JavaScript String.match disagreement

Tags: javascript, regex

This regex `/{(\w+)}/g` is supposed to match every word character *between* the curly braces `{}`. Instead, I'm getting different results in the [**Regex101 JavaScript engine**](https://regex101.com/r/iD4uP6/1) and *Chrome console*.

[image: regex 101 vs js engine]

*Regex101* works as expected, and the `.match` function works without the `g` flag, but it fails to retrieve the contents between curly braces once I apply it (it should fetch `["asd","asd2"]`, and instead it fetches `["{asd}","{asd2}"]`)

Why does this happen? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a negative lookahead followed by your pattern, then a positive lookahead at the end:

```
(\w+)(?=})
```

Resulting in this within the console:

```
"{asd}{asd2}".match(/(\w+)(?=})/g);
```

Example:

https://regex101.com/r/uL9rN0/1

Output:

```
Array [ "asd", "asd2" ]
```

Comment: I choose yours because you used `.match` :)

Comment: Thanks; I try to deviate as little as possible from the original. Interesting problem too with something seemingly so simple.

Comment: That's good! One more thing, do you know exactly why yours works and mine doesn't?

Comment: Yes, if you go back to your original regex you'll see that the curly braces are actually highlighted too. Unless you either use a substitution or come up with another way of ignoring them they appear in the `match` results. I didn't substitute anything I used the lookaheads to skip over the them.

Comment: Ah, yes! Thank you very much, I think you should add that explanation to your answer :)

Comment: The look-ahead is simply useless, since `\w+` already negate the `{`. You can technically shorten it to `(\w+)(?=})`, but it will not guarantee a `{` in front.

Answer (score 7):

The [`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) function returns an array of all matches when the 'g' flag is added to the pattern.

You want to use [`RegExp.prototype.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) function to get the capture groups:

The exec() saves the last index of the match it found in the RegExp object and continues from there when you run it the next time. So, you need to loop over your string until the function returns null to get all the matches.

[Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mh8g6egx/)

```
var str = "this {is} a {word} {test}";
var re = /{(\w+)}/g;
do{
var res = re.exec(str);
console.log(res);
} while( res );
```

Comment: Thanks! But using `/{(\w+)}/g.exec("{asd}{asd2}")` matches `["{asd}","asd"]`, so, only the first occurrence. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @undefined I just copied this code from regex101's code generator: http://jsfiddle.net/7qwmj4bo/

Comment: @undefined Sorry for my incomplete answer, I have updated the answer with an explanation.

Comment: Thanks! Very nice answer, I chose **@l'L'l**'s answer because he managed to do it with the `.match` function, but yours is really good too!