# Regex that matches every nth occurences of character

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I have found solutions for finding nth occurrence but could not find about finding every nth occurrences.

I have string such as "`key1~value1~key2~value2~key3~value3~`".

What is the regex that will match every second occurrence of the `~`?

key1~value1`~`key2~value2`~`key3~value3`~`

I am trying to create a custom Pattern Analizer for Elasticsearch that is the regex should match the token seperators instead of tokens.

Comment: So your match would be `value1 value2 value3`?

Comment: You just need [`([^~]+)~([^~]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/tD9eP5/1)

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ no my match will be 2nd, 4th,.. `~` character. @Wiktor that matches `key~value` pairs. What I want is just the opposite of that.

Comment: @alpert: Why do you need to only get the even `~`s? (I thought you wanted to get the key-value pairs by splitting at the even `~`s.) What should be the final result? What is the language?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I am trying to create a custom Pattern analizer for elasticsearch that the regex should match the token seperators instead of tokens: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-analyzer.html

Comment: So, it uses Java regex.

Comment: Yes. It uses java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
~(?=(?:[^~]*~[^~]*~)*[^~]*$)
```

The pattern matches:

- `~` - a tilde that is followed by...
- `(?=(?:[^~]*~[^~]*~)*[^~]*$)` - 0+ non-tildes + `~` x 2 times, 0+ times, and then 0+ non-tildes up to the end of string. So, this check makes sure there is an even number of tildes up to the end of string after matching the first tilde.

[image]

Comment: It would be better practice to find an example that will also work with odd number of instances but that olso fixed my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that there are not an even number of `~` before:

```
(?<!^([^~]*~[^~]*~)*[^~]*)~
```

[Try it online!](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%21%5E%28%5B%5E%7E%5D%2A%7E%5B%5E%7E%5D%2A%7E%29%2A%5B%5E%7E%5D%2A%29%7E&i=key1%7evalue1%7ekey2%7evalue2%7ekey3%7evalue3%7e)

---

#### How it works:

```
(?<!^([^~]*~[^~]*~)*[^~]*)~    Our regex.
                          ~    Matches a tilde (~).
(?<!                     )     Assert that before it is not:
    ^                              the beginning
     (            )*               followed by zero or more times:
      [^~]*~[^~]*~                     two tildes, no matter what comes within
                    [^~]*          followed by non-tildes.
```

Comment: This will only work in .NET, Vim (with a different syntax), and PyPi regex Python module (and JGSoft) regex flavors. To some extent, this approach will work in Java. The problem is that the pattern in the lookbehind is of infinite-width, and most languages that support a lookbehind only support a fixed-width lookbehind version.

Comment: Would positive lookbehind be supported in more flavours?

Comment: I am getting "Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length" error when I tryied to use it with elasticsearch which uses Java. Is there a more general way that will also work with java?

Answer (score 0):

First group of non-overlapping occurrences of `~.*?(~)`. Try: http://regexr.com/3dc15.

Comment: That matches `~value~` pairs. That is not what I want to.

Comment: @alpert First group matches `~`.

Comment: [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28920448/5612697) to understand how to use this regex